# Mailer: Sending emails using Ruby on Rails failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a database of users in my Ruby on Rails app, and now I'm trying to create a mailer that send emails to all users in my database whenever I want.

Here's my model:

```
class MailMessage < ActionMailer::Base

  def contact(recipient, subject, message)
    # host = Hobo::Controller.request_host
    # app_name = Hobo::Controller.app_name || host
    @subject    = subject
    # @body       = { :user => user, :host => host, :app_name => app_name }
    @body["title"] = 'This is title'
    @body["email"] = 'mark@doc.org.uk'
    @body["message"] = message
    @recipients = recipient
    @from       = 'no-reply@doc.org.uk'
    @sent_on    = Time.now
    @headers    = {}
  end
end
```

Here's my controller:

```
class MailMessageController < ApplicationController
  def sendmail
    email = @params["email"]
    recipient = email["recipient"]
    subject = email["subject"]
    message = email["message"]
    MailMessage.deliver_contact(recipient, subject, message)
    return if request.xhr?
    render :text => 'Message sent successfully'
  end

  def index
    render :file => 'app/views/mail_message/index.html'
  end  
end
```

Here's my `views/mail_message`:

```
<h1>Send Email</h1>

<%= form_tag :action => 'sendmail' %>
  <p>
    <label for="email_subject">Subject</label>
    <%= text_field 'email', 'subject' %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email_recipient">Recipient</label>
    <%= text_field 'email', 'recipient' %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email_message">Message</label>
    <%= text_area 'email', 'message' %>
  </p>
  <%= submit_tag "Send" %>
<%= form_tag %>
```

Here's my `enviroment.rb`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
  ActionMailer::Base.sendmail_settings = {
        :location       => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
        :arguments      => '-i -t'
  }

  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true # the "deliver_*" methods are available
  ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
  ActionMailer::Base.default_charset = "utf-8"
  ActionMailer::Base.default_content_type = "text/html" # default: "text/plain"
  ActionMailer::Base.default_mime_version = "1.0"
  ActionMailer::Base.default_implicit_parts_order = [ "text/html", "text/plain"]
```

When I run a test message, I get the following error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
app/controllers/mail_message_controller.rb:4:in `sendmail'
```

It doesn't seem to recognise `sendmail`, but I have given its location. Any clues for how to fix this error will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this line is the problem:

```
@params["email"]
```

If it's meant to be the data from the form, drop the @.

Answer (score 1):

@params isint initialized in your controller.

You probably simple want to use params to get your http action parameters.